# I am using vue-resource with vue cli webpack i have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
mounted(){
 this.$http.get('http:anotherurl.com/api/data.xml')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

i get this console error :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

i test **vue-resource** with reddit and it worked fine but with this url gives  the problem . please help .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people who set up `anotherurl.com` have configured it to not allow requests via JavaScript from sites other than their own. This is a feature of HTTP / CORS.

For further reading, the Mozilla documentation explains a little more about what is going on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: i even set Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * wildcard but still issue with ajax request , but if i put the url in the browser , the browser will recieve the xml data in a page , do u think it is an issue with the api

Comment: i think u were right ... i told the backend and they told me **the surprise** it is not allow requests via JavaScript using another server ... thx for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome you can get an extension to ignore xframe-headers. don't know how to solve it in production though

Comment: i know about the extension put can't use it in production thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

I would say that as vue-resource is deprecated from 2.0 v you should look at newer API like this one here - https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Axios is powerful-promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

Comment: i tested with axios and jquery but still the same . api like reddit works fine but this api still has issue

Comment: vue-ressource is *not* deprecated, it is merely no longer part of the [official recommendation](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4).

Comment: yea apology man, ya it is no longer part of vue.js after vue 2.0 in documentation